# Error 400 and error 503 by /customer/section/load/? and ?sections=messages

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.2.6

I have upgraded my stage site from Magento 2.2.9 to 2.3.3, but now it's getting long loading time by the

> /customer/section/load/?sections=gtm&force_new_section_timestamp=false&_=...

and

> ?sections=messages....

I'm not sure if it's caused by default Magento or 3rd party extension. I have tried to change to default luma theme and disabled 3rd party extensions, but no luck. Below is the screenshot from the google chrome developer tab.

[image]

i get these server error logs after my stage site hits 503 server unavailable.  However, my stage site files are at `/home/demo4756/stage2/index.php`. the "public_html/" is for live site. any ideas?

> [Tue Oct 29 12:06:33.935692 2019] [:error] [pid 32922] Execute of
>   /home/demo4756/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 109.04
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:06:33.933996 2019] [:error] [pid 32922] Execute of
>   /home/demo4756/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 109.04
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:06:33.697460 2019] [:error] [pid 32089] Execute of
>   /home/demo4756/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 109.04
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:06:33.696386 2019] [:error] [pid 32089] Execute of
>   /home/demo4756/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 109.04
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:06:03.834089 2019] [:error] [pid 32957] Execute of
>   /home/demo4756/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 91.28
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:06:03.783058 2019] [:error] [pid 32957] Execute of
>   /home/demo4756/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 91.28
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:06:02.346288 2019] [:error] [pid 32957] Execute of
>   /home/demo4756/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 66.93
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:06:02.344956 2019] [:error] [pid 32957] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 66.93
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:06:00.001466 2019] [:error] [pid 32941] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 66.93
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:05:59.999731 2019] [:error] [pid 32941] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 66.93
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:05:59.757994 2019] [:error] [pid 32950] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 66.93
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:05:59.757285 2019] [:error] [pid 32950] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 66.93
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:05:57.837707 2019] [:error] [pid 32952] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/stage2/index.php stopped because of load 66.93 [Tue Oct
>   29 12:05:57.836374 2019] [:error] [pid 32952] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/stage2/index.php stopped because of load 66.93 [Tue Oct
>   29 12:05:55.614984 2019] [:error] [pid 32950] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 37.94
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:05:55.563016 2019] [:error] [pid 32950] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 37.94
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:05:53.816650 2019] [:error] [pid 32956] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 37.94
>   [Tue Oct 29 12:05:53.815636 2019] [:error] [pid 32956] Execute of
>   /home/myuserid/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 37.94

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check your webserver logs (apache logs) if there are reported PHP errors that caused the 400 and 503. Most likely there is a code issue when Magento tries to call the path.

Comment: thank you i will check the webserver logs

Comment: i added some error logs. i get these server error logs ( ex:/home/demo4756/public_html/index.php stopped because of load 109.04 ) after my stage site hits 503 server unavailable.  However, my stage site files are at /home/demo4756/stage2/index.php. the "public_html" is for live site. any ideas?